# Magento 2 gets stuck in maintenance mode when deploying to production mode

Tags: magento, deployment, magento2

I recently put my Magento 2 project in developer mode so I could enable path hints and re-compile some of the LESS code. When I went to put the site back into production mode, it appears to stall in the terminal and then the whole site just returns an error message.

```
magento deploy:mode:set production

# it gets this far before failing
Enabled maintenance
Starting compilation
```

At this point, I have to disable maintenance mode and put it back into developer mode in order to bring the site back up. This is the message that I get once the site goes down from attempting putting it into production mode.

```
Exception #0 (Exception): Unable to proceed: the maintenance mode is enabled
```

My only successful attempt at getting around this was to use the `--skip-compilation` flag when setting the mode to production mode. However, doing this seemed to leave me with missing javascript assets for the checkout process, thus disabling the checkout process all together.

Any ideas how to properly deploy Magento 2 without issues like this?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to successfully get everything properly deployed once I re-deployed static assets after putting it into production mode while using the `--skip-compilation` flag. Still feels like I had to hack my way to deployment, but what's done is done.